# Npm i react don't run

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Hello everyone I want to install reactjs in a project that I just created but when I run command npm I react it causes an error

```
**npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...943","tarball":"https'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\HP Notebook\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-11T13_31_27_071Z-debug.log**
```

### Package JSON

```
    {
  "name": "react-lab",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "lab sur reactjs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Orion WAMBERT",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
    "expressjs": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "latest-version": "^4.0.0",
    "mobx": "^5.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you run npm init before. If yes can you share your package.json file?

Comment: Please update your question and share this log file's content. In the meanwhile you can try this: `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I just updated my question specifying the package json

Comment: "npm I react" this is command you are running?

Comment: yes i executed the command `npm i react`  i diminutive of `install`